# How does a wordpress plugin save settings information?

Tags: php, database, wordpress

How does a WordPress plugin save settings information ?

For example, where does it keep the template information that we enter in WordPress panel ?

In a database or in define functions? What is the best way?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/settings/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is that you can register, save and read the extra information using with **WordPress Plugin settings with form.**

You have to follow the steps as mentioned in articles with birfe information.

**First Step,** You can "add form to WordPress plugin page" in **functions.php** file as mentioned in article file. - [Save WordPress plugin settings with form](https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/wordpress-development/save-wordpress-plugin-settings-with-form)

**Second Step,** you can register the Register WordPress plugin settings to database -
[Register WordPress plugin settings to database](https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/wordpress-development/register-wordpress-plugin-settings-to-database)

**Third Step,** you can implement to read WordPress plugin settings from database - [Read WordPress plugin settings from database](https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/wordpress-development/read-wordpress-plugin-settings-from-database)

Edit: Since the links are down take a look at [this](https://blog.wplauncher.com/create-wordpress-plugin-settings-page/) Guide